# Cannot access route with auth guard in app controller, validate function in local strategy file wont execute NestJs

Tags: javascript, typescript, rest, nestjs, prisma

I try to acces my login route in the app.controller.ts for my rest api with Nestjs and Prisma, but i end up with a 401 error as a response.
I have been following nestjs official documentation (https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication).

./app.controller.ts :

```
import { LocalAuthGuard } from './auth/local-auth.guards';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(
    private readonly appService: AppService,
    private readonly authService: AuthService,
  ) {}

  @UseGuards(LocalAuthGuard)
  @Post('auth/login')
  async login(@Request() req) {
    return req.user;
  }
```

./auth/local.strategy.ts:

```
import { Strategy } from 'passport-local';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    super();
  }

  async validate(username: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser(username, password);
    console.log('validation');

    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

./auth/local-auth.guards.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class LocalAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('local') {}
```

basically from what i understand, the use of `@UseGuards(LocalAuthGuard)` will allow access to the `/auth/login` function if the `validate(username: string, password: string)` doesnt throw, unfortunaly it never execute and i keep getting that 401 error coming from somewhere but i have no clue (hence this post).

Thank you for reading, and your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Nine times out of ten, this is because you aren't sending a `POST` request with body parameters of `username` and `password`. If you want to use something like `email` instead you need to pass the object `{ usernameField: 'email' }` to `super()` in the `constructor()` of your `LocalStrategy`. If that's *not* the case, then more details will be needed to be added to your question such as what your request looks like.

You can also try adding this snippet to your `LocalAuthGuard` to get a better idea of what is happening when that error comes through:

```js
handleRequest(...args: Parameters<InstanceType<ReturnType<typeof AuthGuard>>['handleRequest']> {
  console.log(args);
  return super.handleRequest(...args);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the snippet, i will use it for debug purpose.

I solved the issue by changing the usernameField by default to 'email' (i am sending the email in the password in the response) located in the ./auth/local.strategy.ts in the call of 'super()' in the constructor "    super({ usernameField: 'email' });"